# How to See the Call Trace in Trace 32

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

Can anyone help we out to see the Call Trace in the Trace 32 debugger. I remember such option is available in UDE debugger. Is such option available in the Trace32 as well.

Example:-When a interrupt has raised then I wanted to know what all function s are called in sequence before reaching my break point(if have a break point in some part of code).

Answer (score 2):

To view the call stack use command `Frame.view` (or `Var.Frame` if you have an older copy of TRACE32). From the Menu it is View > Stackframe.